# React - Increment/Decrement Button for table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement an increment button in React that will update the value of a field in a table by one. Specifically, I am trying to increment the "stock" by one

This is what I'm currently trying:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {

      super(props);

      this.state = {

          cars: [
              {
                  "manufacturer": "Toyota",
                  "model": "Rav4",
                  "year": 2008,
                  "stock": 3,
                  "price": 8500
              },
              {
                  "manufacturer": "Toyota",
                  "model": "Camry",
                  "year": 2009,
                  "stock": 2,
                  "price": 6500
              },
              {
                  "manufacturer": "Toyota",
                  "model": "Tacoma",
                  "year": 2016,
                  "stock": 1,
                  "price": 22000
              },
              {
                  "manufacturer": "BMW",
                  "model": "i3",
                  "year": 2012,
                  "stock": 5,
                  "price": 12000
              },
              {
                  "manufacturer": "Chevy",
                  "model": "Malibu",
                  "year": 2015,
                  "stock": 2,
                  "price": 10000
              },
              {
                  "manufacturer": "Honda",
                  "model": "Accord",
                  "year": 2013,
                  "stock": 1,
                  "price": 9000
              },
              {
                  "manufacturer": "Hyundai",
                  "model": "Elantra",
                  "year": 2013,
                  "stock": 2,
                  "price": 7000
              },
              {
                  "manufacturer": "Chevy",
                  "model": "Cruze",
                  "year": 2012,
                  "stock": 2,
                  "price": 5500
              },
              {
                  "manufacturer": "Dodge",
                  "model": "Charger",
                  "year": 2013,
                  "stock": 2,
                  "price": 16000
              },
              {
                  "manufacturer": "Ford",
                  "model": "Mustang",
                  "year": 2009,
                  "stock": 1,
                  "price": 8000
              },
          ]
      };
  }
  
  onHeaderClick(){
   
  }

  increaseStock(event){
    this.setState({cars: this.state.cars.stock + 1})
  }


  decreaseStock(event){
    this.setState({cars: this.state.cars.stock + 1})         
  }

  render() {
      return (
          <table>
              <tr>
                  <th>Manufacturer</th>
                  <th>Model</th>
                  <th onClick={()=> this.onHeaderClick}>Year</th>
                  <th>Stock</th>
                  <th>Price</th>
                  <th>Options</th>
                  <th></th>
              </tr>
              {
                  this.state.cars.map(car => (
                      <tr key={car.model}>
                          <td>{car.manufacturer}</td>
                          <td>{car.model}</td>
                          <td>{car.year}</td>
                          <td>{car.stock}</td>
                          <td>${car.price}.00</td>
                          <td><button type="button" onClick={this.increaseStock.bind(this)}>Increment</button></td>
                          <td><button type="button" onClick={this.decreaseStock.bind(this)}>Decrement</button></td>
                      </tr>
                  ))
              }

          </table>
      );
  };
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"))
```

I have tried a bunch of different implementations all to no avail. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Both increase and decrese functions both do `+ 1` ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: `this.state.cars.stock + 1` does does nothing.  You'll need to update the `.stock` of the current selected row. `cars` is an array

Comment: At a glance, you're setting *the entire array* to a number: `{cars: this.state.cars.stock + 1}`  Additionally, an array doesn't have a property called `stock`.  Are you trying to increment *every* item in the array, or *a specific* item in the array?  The code isn't making that clear.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to update the whole array `cars` (which will end up being just a number) and not the specific `car` object.

What you should do it pass the current `car` as parameter at your function and update the `state` accordingly

```
<td><button type="button" onClick={() => increaseStock(car)}>Increment</button></td>
```

**method**

```
  increaseStock = car => {
    const index = this.state.cars.findIndex(cr => cr.model === car.model)
    
    let newCar = { ...this.state.cars[index] }
    newCar.stock += 1
    
    this.setState({ ...this.state, cars: Object.assign([ ...this.state.cars ], { [index]: newCar }) })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

TLDR;
You should update the `stock` value for a specific car from the array, not the `cars` array itself. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74288623/7119067) seems to work.

Suggestion:
As suggested in the [official ReactJS documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-1-break-the-ui-into-a-component-hierarchy) try to breakdown into smaller components.
In your case, the `<tr>` from the map function can easily be extracted as a separate component (e.g. `CarModelItem`). Or even deeper to extract the buttons in a separate component. After splitting that you can just pass the `increaseStock` and `increaseStock` as callbacks to those components props.

Answer (score 0):

To start, you need to add a unique id for each element

```
cars: [{
        id: 1,
        manufacturer: "Toyota",
        model: "Rav4",
        year: 2008,
        stock: 3,
        price: 8500
       }, 
       {
        id: 2,
        //...
       }]
```

And now, you have to find the element with its id in your array then increment or decrement stock

```
increment(id) {
  let items = [...this.state.cars];
  const index = items.map(item => item.id).indexOf(id);

  let item = {...this.state.cars[index]};
  item.stock = item.stock + 1;

  items[index] = item;    
  this.setState({items});
}


decrement(id) {
  let items = [...this.state.cars];
  const index = items.map(item => item.id).indexOf(id);

  let item = {...this.state.cars[index]};
  item.stock = item.stock - 1; // maybe you need to check if stock = 0

  items[index] = item;    
  this.setState({items});       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an array of cars in state you need to find a way to identify which model is meant to be updated. In this example I've attached a data attribute to the button which can be picked up in functions.

In the class methods make a copy of the cars state, [find the index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) of the car that you want to update, increase/decrease its stock value, and then update the state.

Note: it's better to `bind` your class methods in the constructor.

```js
const { Component } = React;

class Example extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={cars:[{manufacturer:"Toyota",model:"Rav4",year:2008,stock:3,price:8500},{manufacturer:"Toyota",model:"Camry",year:2009,stock:2,price:6500},{manufacturer:"Toyota",model:"Tacoma",year:2016,stock:1,price:22e3},{manufacturer:"BMW",model:"i3",year:2012,stock:5,price:12e3},{manufacturer:"Chevy",model:"Malibu",year:2015,stock:2,price:1e4},{manufacturer:"Honda",model:"Accord",year:2013,stock:1,price:9e3},{manufacturer:"Hyundai",model:"Elantra",year:2013,stock:2,price:7e3},{manufacturer:"Chevy",model:"Cruze",year:2012,stock:2,price:5500},{manufacturer:"Dodge",model:"Charger",year:2013,stock:2,price:16e3},{manufacturer:"Ford",model:"Mustang",year:2009,stock:1,price:8e3}]};
    this.increaseStock = this.increaseStock.bind(this);
    this.decreaseStock = this.decreaseStock.bind(this);
  }
  
  increaseStock(event) {
    const { model } = event.target.dataset;
    const cars = [...this.state.cars];
    const index = cars.findIndex(car => car.model === model);
    if (index >= 0) {
      ++cars[index].stock;
      this.setState({ cars });
    }
  }

  decreaseStock(event) {
    const { model } = event.target.dataset;
    const cars = [...this.state.cars];
    const index = cars.findIndex(car => car.model === model);
    if (index >= 0) {
      --cars[index].stock;
      this.setState({ cars });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Manufacturer</th>
          <th>Model</th>
          <th onClick={()=> this.onHeaderClick}>Year</th>
          <th>Stock</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Options</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
        {
          this.state.cars.map(car => (
            <tr key={car.model}>
              <td>{car.manufacturer}</td>
              <td>{car.model}</td>
              <td>{car.year}</td>
              <td>{car.stock}</td>
              <td>${car.price}.00</td>
              <td>
                <button
                  data-model={car.model}
                  type="button"
                  onClick={this.increaseStock}
                >Increment
                </button>
              </td>
              <td>
                <button
                  data-model={car.model}
                  type="button"
                  onClick={this.decreaseStock}
                >Decrement
                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))
        }
      </table>
    );
  };

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```